# Loading textures in another Thread using detachNewThreadSelector

Tags: opengl-es, textures, nsthread

I am loading 3D model in my iPhone app. since models can be big I want to load it in another thread. I called detachNewThreadSelector to spawn new thread and simply moved model loading call there. Model loads but it has no textures. When I check in debugger I see that glGenTextures call does not create new name/Id (it leaves valiable at 0).

If I move my function call to main thread all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL only works when you create a OpenGL context, and the context is made current for only one thread, so to use OpenGL in another thread, you have to create another context for that thread, and make it current in that thread.

Also it's usual to share resources (via something similar to wglShareLists) between contexts.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention - this is on OpenGL ES on iPhone. Is there example somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using sharegroup. Here is code that did it for me:

Main thread:

> [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(load:)
>   toTarget:[AsynchModelLoader class] withObject:self];

Spawned thread:

> +(void)       load:(id)param {
>   NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
>   ModelViewer* mview = (ModelViewer*)param;
>
> EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1
>   sharegroup:mview.context.sharegroup];
>   [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:aContext];
>
> mview.lib = [Importer fromResource:@"model3d"];
>
> [pool drain]; 
>   }